# Why is custom_audience_third_party_id always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am adding Facebook analytics in iOS app. I added some event from client side but latter we thought we can also add some event from server side. For sending Facebook analytics event from server side, Back end team need custom_audience_third_party_id.

According to FB-
custom_audience_third_party_id:  This ID is an encrypted encoding of the Facebook user's ID and the invoking Facebook app ID.
 Multiple calls with the same user will return different IDs, thus these IDs cannot be used to correlate behavior
 across devices or applications, and are only meaningful when sent back to Facebook for creating Custom Audiences.

The ID retrieved represents the Facebook user identified in the following way: if the specified access token is valid,
 the ID will represent the user associated with that token; otherwise the ID will represent the user logged into the
 native Facebook app on the device.  If there is no native Facebook app, no one is logged into it, or the user has opted out
 at the iOS level from ad tracking, then a `nil` ID will be returned.

This method returns `nil` if either the user has opted-out (via iOS) from Ad Tracking, the app itself has limited event usage
 via the `[FBSDKSettings limitEventAndDataUsage]` flag, or a specific Facebook user cannot be identified.

For getting "custom_audience_third_party_id" : I send one request event.

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [FBSDKAppEvents requestForCustomAudienceThirdPartyIDWithAccessToken:[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]];

 [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (error) {
           NSLog(@"ERROR in FB %@",[error description]);
      } else {
           NSLog(@"result is %@", result);
           NSLog(@"custom_audience_third_party_id ==%@", [result valueForKey:@"custom_audience_third_party_id"]);
      }
 }];
```

But `[result valueForKey:@"custom_audience_third_party_id"]` is always coming `nil`.

I read FB documentation but still not able to know exact issue (Why is `[result valueForKey:@"custom_audience_third_party_id"]` always `nil`.)

Comment: So just to be 100% sure, have you verified that in your case:
(a) the access token is valid, or the Facebook app is installed and someone is logged in,
(b) the user has not opted out from Ad tracking, and 
(c) the app has not limited event usage

Comment: Even Android developer facing same issue. Now, we are using IDFA (mobile advertiser id) for iOS

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be SDK Bug or/and a bug at their end-point (graph-api) for generating third_party_id. Which was the case in android. We tried it with 4.0.1 without any success. Upgrading to 4.2.0 worked without making any additional changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem in my app by adding a short delay before sending the request, even with a `nil` Access Token...

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [FBSDKAppEvents requestForCustomAudienceThirdPartyIDWithAccessToken:nil];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
        NSString *thirdPartyId = result[@"custom_audience_third_party_id"];
        if(thirdPartyId != nil){
            // Do what you must with the ID
        }

    }];
});
```